# I want to know how to solve the issue with connecting to SSMS

Tags: ssms

### I have a problem connecting to the SSMS software. It was working perfectly until suddenly I couldn't connect anymore. I've tried troubleshooting and made sure that my computer is set as my server, but when I try to connect to the software, it gives me an error. Here is the error message.TITLE: Connect to Database Engine

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-P2D72KU.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-2-database-engine-error

---

The system cannot find the file specified

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I would really appreciate some help.

Note: SSMS stands for SQL Server Management Studio, a software used for managing and administering SQL Server databases.

I tried restarting and I also attempted the suggested fix provided by the installed software. I even uninstalled the SSMS software and reinstalled it, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: First, you're not connecting TO ssms. You're using SSMS to connect to SQL server. Are you sure the SQL service is running? What happens when you try to connect to just "localhost"?

Comment: It records the error I put in the question

Comment: Are you sure the SQL service is running on your local machine?